# How do you manage a temporary directory such that it is guaranteed to be deleted on program close?

Tags: garbage-collection, python

I'm working with a temporary directory and I want to make sure that it gets deleted on program close (regardless of whether the program was successful). I'm using `tempfile.mkdtemp`to create the directory and putting the string that's created into a subclass of `str` that deletes the directory on its `__del__` command:

```
import shutil
import tempfile

class TempDir(str):
    """ container for temporary directory. 
    Deletes directory when garbage collected/zero references """
    def __del__(self):
        shutil.rmtree(self.__str__(), onerror=my_error_fn)

dbdir = TempDir(tempfile.mkdtemp())
```

Here's what I'm not sure about: if the program closes or a KeyboardInterrupt happens, will Python automatically delete/garbage collect all the variables?  If not, how could I make sure that the directory gets deleted?

Related info about [creating destructor methods in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/).  Seems like so long as the TempDir object doesn't reference anything else, using `__del__` to destruct it should be fine.

Comment: What have you found when you've tested it? Does `__del__` execute every time you Ctrl+C?

Comment: okay, just added the results of my testing -- thank you very much for the suggestion @JoelCornett!

Comment: Consider using the `atexit` module in addition to `__del__`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `__del__` method, the semantics are unreliable, and could interfere with garbage collection.  Use a context manager: define a `__enter__` and `__exit__` method, and put your use of the object in a `with` statement.  It's clear, it's explicit, and it will work without worry.

Or, another way to make a context manager:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def tempdir(prefix='tmp'):
    """A context manager for creating and then deleting a temporary directory."""
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix)
    try:
        yield tmpdir
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```

Comment: question about this: I want to use this directory to create a number of files and then only delete it either: (1) when the program ends or (2) when all references to files in the directory are gone (meaning that, in my implementation, all references to the TempDir class would also be gone.)  Would this format be able to do that?

Comment: I guess an additional point here: it doesn't really work to just use this in a with statement -- people using the package are going to be manipulating, adding/removing files throughout and the temporary files should be transparent to them. It doesn't seem like that's a good fit for the context manager.

Comment: Jeff, you are right, the context manager is good when the lifetime of a resource matches a lexical scope.  The context manager can still be used at the top level of your program to deal with program exit, while other object references can be explicitly managed to deal with files referencing the directory.

Comment: Okay, so if I'm using this in the context of a package (and it would be fine to just create one global directory and use that throughout), would I add it to the global `__init__.py` file and then somehow make it available to all subpackages/submodules?

Comment: added [this link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/) above, which provides a good context for what I'm looking to do. I'm using the directory as a store for multiple `shelve` objects, and saving/deleting those objects will be handled individually.  Could I do it through a `from mypackage import TEMPDIR` import at the top of each file?

Comment: Note that Python 3.2 added `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` which does the same thing that this answer shows.  For 3.2 and newer I would use the library module code; for older Python versions I would use this code, but I'd rename the function to `TemporaryDirectory()` and document that it is similar to the 3.2 code.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 12):

I needed something similar for a package test suite that depended on the existence of a specific (semi-mocked) file structure. With many test modules I don't always know which tests will be run and in what order, or how the test run will exit.

Using `__del__` at application exit is unreliable in my experience. And using context manager would mean rewriting the test files to make sure everything wraps nicely. Instead I use `atexit`. In `<package>.tests.__init__` I just added:

```py
import atexit, shutil, tempfile

test_area = tempfile.mkdtemp()
atexit.register(shutil.rmtree, test_area)
```

Python will then call `shutil.rmtree(test_area)` at exit. Keyword arguments for error handling may also be added if required.

Answer (score 1):

It deletes everything only when the program ends (like it normally would).

To illustrate, here's the code I used:

```
import tempfile
import shutil
import os

class TempDir(str):
    """ container for temporary directory. Deletes directory when garbage
    collected/zero references """
    def __del__(self):
        print "deleting temporary files in directory {}".format(self.__str__())
        shutil.rmtree(self.__str__(), onerror=delete_dir_handler)

def delete_dir_handler(listdir_fn, dirname, exception):
    try:
        for fileobj in listdir_fn(dirname):
            os.remove(fileobj)
        os.removedirs(dirname)
    except (AttributeError, OSError, TypeError):
        print exception[1]
        print "Sorry. Couldn't delete directory {}.".format(dirname)
        raise

test = TempDir(tempfile.mkdtemp())
```

And output:

```
$ python my_file.py
deleting temporary files in directory /var/folders/A9/A9xrfjrXGsq9Cf0eD2jf0U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpG3h1qD
```

If you run it in interactive mode, it doesn't delete until you exit the program.

```
$ python -i my program 
>>> # pressed Ctrl-C here
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> # again, Ctrl-C
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> # Ctrl-D to exit
deleting temporary files in directory /var/folders/A9/A9xrfjrXGsq9Cf0eD2jf0U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpMBGt5n
```

Finally, if you add a `raw_input('')` line to the file, it will behave exactly the same as program end if you press Ctrl-C.